# Push to Bitbucket: ssh: Could not resolve hostname bitbucket.org:username: No such file or directory

Tags: git, bitbucket

I tried to push my work to Bitbucket, and I followed these steps:

```
git init 
git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/tardjo/test.git
git push -u origin --all
```

but when I `git push` like above, I get the following error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname bitbucket.org:tardjo: No such file or directory
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Are you sure that your username is "username" ?

Comment: and assuming you'd be using correct username, have you created the repo on bitbucket?

Comment: Sorry all my real username is tardjo, how to fix it my problem?

Comment: i already git add and git commit first

Comment: So why do you have `--all`? Do you have multiple branches to push or just one?

Comment: You should add git add and git commit steps to your question as well, currently it's misleading. Also, you still didn't mention if you've created the repo on bitbucket first. Added an answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the remote like this

```
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:tardjo/test.git
```

Answer (score 1):

When pushing for the first time, normally you'd use the format `git push -u origin master`. Don't leave out the master part, it'll specify where you're pushing from. After you've done it once you can leave it out afterwards, since using `-u` you're saying it would be the default later on.

`--all` is for pushing multiple branches, which apparently you don't have, so you don't need that.

Also, you didn't mention if you've created the repo first on bitbucket. For the commands you use, you should have created it there first.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I knew what the issue was, but for me, I swapped out the hostname (`bitbucket.org`) with an IP from their website: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/what-are-the-bitbucket-cloud-ip-addresses-i-should-use-to-configure-my-corporate-firewall-343343385.html

Then update your repo details with the IP instead: `git remote add origin git@104.192.143.1/name/repo.git`

Answer (score -1):

[ I know it is old but just for record ]

Add origin as http:// protocol instead of ssh://

```
git remote add origin http://httpversionoforigin.git
```